# NSMutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod not setting the correct Method

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I have this request to an API which should POST some json:

```
class func makeAPICall (serializedJSONObject contentMap: Dictionary<String, String>, completion: ((data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void)) throws -> Void {
        var jsonData: NSData
        do {
            jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(contentMap, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
            var jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
            print(jsonString)
            jsonString = jsonString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormUrlencoded()!
            print(jsonString)
            jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let postsEndpoint: String = "https://www.example.com/api/v2"
            guard let postsURL = NSURL(string: postsEndpoint) else {
                throw APICallError.other("cannot create URL")
            }
            let postsURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: postsURL)
            print(jsonData)
            postsURLRequest.HTTPBody = jsonData
            print(postsURLRequest)
            postsURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(postsURLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                completion(data: data, response: response, error: error)
            })
            task.resume() //starts the request. It's called resume() because a session starts in a suspended state
        } catch {
            print("lol, problem")
        }
    }
```

with extension (for `x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding):

```
extension String {
    func stringByAddingPercentEncodingForFormUrlencoded() -> String? {
        let characterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
        characterSet.addCharactersInString("-._* ")

        return stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(characterSet)?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
    }
}
```

now I also have this simple test page to test json requests:

```
<form action="v2/" method="post">
    <textarea name="data" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

the server logs all requests so that way I found out that my app is actually using GET instead of POST

app request log:

```
GET /api/v2/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */\*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=vd61qutdll216hbs3a677fgsq4
User-Agent: KM%20registratie%20tabbed%20NL/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.2.0
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

Request body:
```

(notice the request body is also empty, but I'll make a different question for that)

html form request log:

```
POST /api/v2/ HTTP/1.1

HTTP headers:
Host: www.example.com
Origin: http://www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/\*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9
Referer: http://www.example.com/api/test.php
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Request body:
data=%7B%22action%22%3A+%22vehicleRecords%22%2C%0D%0A%22token%22%3A+%22token_04e01fdc78205f0f6542bd523519e12fd3329ba9%22%2C%0D%0A%22vehicle%22%3A+%22vehicle_e5b79b2e%22%7D
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get access to the project on GitHub, or something like that?

Comment: The UTF8EncodedJSON, is it of type NSData?

Comment: yes (it doesn't compile if it's not anyway). Also, why would that change the HTTPMethod?

Comment: At first my friend, calm down... Im trying to help you... OK? I don´t know what you have tried...

Comment: I will send you some code you will need to try in an answer, give me a second

Comment: lol, I don't really understand what you're offended by...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url should have a trailing forward-slash so: `"www.example.com/api/v2/"`

Comment: Suppose it was an error in your api then rather then your Swift code. Oh well, glad you got it anyway.

Comment: yes.. I kinda know what was going on now, but lets leave it at that it's an API made with PHP :p

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this out at first?

```
if let postEndpoint: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/api/v2") {
    let postURLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: postEndpoint)
    postURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    postURLRequest.HTTPBody = UTF8EncodedJSON

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(postURLRequest, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: I'm calling `task.resume()`, I suppose that doesn't make a difference?

Comment: The difference ist to don't use this NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()... I would like to try if the defaultSesstionConfiguration ist overriding the POST to GET

Answer (score 0):

I only find 2 differences in the way we each handled our code but seeing how post works for me I'll just post it and hope it might be useful.

The configuration and request are made as follows:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let a = apiString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: Utilities.getTranslation("websiteG") + a!)!)
```

Your way is a lot cleaner though so don't use that.

After, I apply the method only after already setting the body although I really doubt setting the method later will fix it.

```
if method == "POST" || method == "PUT" {
     request.HTTPBody = post!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
request.HTTPMethod = method
```

And last but not least the making of the NSURLSession and using it:

```
func httpRequest(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration, request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (NSData?, String?) -> Void) {
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration,
            delegate: self,
            delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    callback(nil, "\(error!.code)")
                } else {
                    let result = NSData(data: data!)
                    callback(result, nil)
                }
        }
        task.resume()
}
```

The only difference I really see if that I assigned the delegates and I used the function "dataTaskWithRequest:" instead of "dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:".

I don't really know for sure if the answer to your question is in here but you might give it a try, if you are wondering which delegate methods I implemented still: "URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:" and "URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:" although I don't think they ever get fired so I am pretty sure you can ignore the assigning of the delegates.

Edit: I'll just write the entire function.

```
func apiCall(method: String = "GET", post: String? = nil, apiString: String, success: (JSONData: NSData!, cancel: Bool!) -> Void) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    //website string
    let a = apiString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: Utilities.getTranslation("websiteG") + a!)!)
    print(request)
    //Define a new API object
    let learn = API()
    //Here is supposed to be some code for creating the base64 authorization string, but because it's not important I decided to remove it.
    //Check if it's sending extra information with the call
    if method == "POST" || method == "PUT" {
        request.HTTPBody = post!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    request.HTTPMethod = method
    //Perform request to the api
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authString]
    learn.httpRequest(configuration, request: request, callback:{(data, error) -> Void in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        if let urlData = data {
            success(JSONData: urlData, cancel: false)
            //Gives back an NSData that can be used for reading data
        } else {
            if error == "-1009" {
                self.delegate?.viewShouldDismissLoading()
            }
            success(JSONData: nil, cancel: true)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: where does your `post` variable come from? I think you meant the same variable as `a` but I'm not sure..
Also, I already tried setting the method after the body but doesn't change anything indeed :(

Comment: I updated the question with my full code. Maybe you can find a problem in another part

Comment: My post variable is an optional string that I pass to my function which is "apiCall(method: String = "GET", post: String? = nil, apiString: String, success: (JSONData: NSData!, cancel: Bool!) -> Void)". Can't really find any differences though :(